# python interpreter keys are swapped

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, keyboard, tty

I am trying to get some kicking in python and decided to run python on my ubuntu natty installation, still I am having a weird problem...

It seems that inside the interpreter my keyboard keys are completely swapped by US keyboard ones, like, when I try to type a <kbd>'</kbd> it gives me a <kbd>?</kbd>.

The thing is, how do I change this setting on python interpreter?

Comment: Are you sure that this is a python problem? Also, this might be a better question for [Superuser](http://superuser.com/)

Comment: this is only happening on python... still that doesn't mean everything. I'll add this question to superuser later. thx for the info!

Comment: Try rebooting the interpreter and monitor the keyboard settings while you do so. Also try manually resetting the keyboard settings after opening the interpreter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't with python. this might help: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/stty.html